# FFmpeg error with video stream

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming

**Please see Edit 2. The problem has been updated.**

**Error 1:** *Writing encrypted data to socket failed av_interleaved_write_frame(): I/O error*

**Error 2:** *(libx264) Conversion failed!*

---

I'm trying to stream using a webcam as data input with FFmpeg, but I need to stream a video in addition to the stream. Both features with the same command for a few minutes.

(If placed separately the code of the recording works perfectly since the one of the streaming does not work and it presents the same error.)

It is also important to say that everything is right with the server.

**FFmpeg code:**

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -rtbufsize 2048M -i "video=Integrated Webcam" -t 300 -c:v libx264 
-segment_atclocktime 1 -segment_format mp4 meuvideo.mp4 -f mpegts -q:v 5 -codec:v 
mpeg1video https://urlexemplo.com.br:8081/rota
```

**Log:**

```
ffmpeg started on 2017-11-20 at 15:52:22
Report written to "ffmpeg-20171120-155222.log"

ffmpeg version 3.3.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers

built with gcc 7.1.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib

  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100

libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100

Input #0, dshow, from 'video=Integrated Webcam':
  Duration: N/A, start: 9581.085000, bitrate: N/A

Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 640x480, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 10000k tbn, 10000k tbc

https://urlexemplo.com.br:8081/rota: Unknown error
```

I ran the -report command and generated a report. You can not paste directly here because it's too big, can be found in the link:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ow76gddst98iolt/ffmpeg-20171120-155222.log?dl=0

**Regardless of how I write the code of FFmpeg always gives error in the url of the output.** Is there any specific way to stream video with HTTP? Any command that is missing and that justifies the error?

---

**Edit 1:**

To test, I put the address udp://@xxx.x.x.x:1234 (xxx.x.x.x -> IP) in place of the url and the command ran, watched streaming with VLC and it still recorded the video appropriately during the five minutes requested.

The question remains: Is there any special parameter for working with HTTP addresses?

**Edit 2:**

The last problem was solved. They gave me the wrong URL. No need to specify a port. Now the error is another one I do not know how to solve, I did not find references of the error presented.

```
    ffmpeg started on 2017-11-28 at 11:15:52
    Report written to "ffmpeg-20171128-111552.log"

    ffmpeg version 3.3.3
    Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
      built with gcc 7.1.0 (GCC)
      configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib

    libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
      libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
      libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
      libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
      libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
      libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
      libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
      libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100

    Input #0, dshow, from 'video=Integrated Webcam':
      Duration: N/A, start: 50683.124000, bitrate: N/A

    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 640x480, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 10000k tbn, 10000k tbc

    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))

    Stream #0:0 -> #1:0 (rawvideo (native) -> mpeg1video (native))
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help

    No pixel format specified, yuv422p for H.264 encoding chosen.
    Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.

    [libx264 @ 0000000000e888e0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX

    [libx264 @ 0000000000e888e0] profile High 4:2:2, level 3.0, 4:2:2 8-bit

    [libx264 @ 0000000000e888e0] 264 - core 152 r2851 ba24899 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
    Output #0, mp4, to './videos/meu_video2017-11-28_11-15-51-950.mp4':
      Metadata:
        encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
        Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv422p, 640x480, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 10000k tbn, 30 tbc
        Metadata:
          encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 libx264
        Side data:
          cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1

    Output #1, mpegts, to 'https://urlexemplo.com.br/rota':

   Metadata:
        encoder         : Lavf57.71.100 
        Stream #1:0: Video: mpeg1video, yuv420p, 640x480, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 30 fps, 90k tbn, 30 tbc
        Metadata:
          encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 mpeg1video
        Side data:
          cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1

    Past duration 0.687492 too large

    Past duration 0.679985 too large

    Past duration 0.609367 too large

    Past duration 0.609993 too large

    frame=   32 fps=0.0 q=0.0 q=5.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.83 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s dup=10 drop=0 speed=1.65x    
    frame=   51 fps= 39 q=29.0 q=5.0 size=       3kB time=00:00:01.43 bitrate=  18.0kbits/s dup=24 drop=0 speed= 1.1x    
    frame=   56 fps= 31 q=29.0 q=5.0 size=      13kB time=00:00:01.56 bitrate=  69.5kbits/s dup=28 drop=0 speed=0.855x    
    frame=   60 fps= 23 q=29.0 q=5.0 size=      25kB time=00:00:01.66 bitrate= 123.1kbits/s dup=31 drop=0 speed=0.638x    
    frame=   84 fps= 26 q=26.0 q=5.0 size=     129kB time=00:00:02.46 bitrate= 427.3kbits/s dup=49 drop=0 speed=0.774x    
    frame=  111 fps= 30 q=29.0 q=5.0 size=     283kB time=00:00:03.40 bitrate= 683.0kbits/s dup=69 drop=0 speed=0.906x    
    C:\apity-desktop-node\src\ffmpeg.js:332 frame=  147 fps= 35 q=29.0 q=5.0 size=     515kB time=00:00:04.60 bitrate= 916.9kbits/s dup=96 drop=0 speed=1.08x    
    frame=  163 fps= 34 q=29.0 q=5.0 size=     620kB time=00:00:05.16 bitrate= 983.2kbits/s dup=108 drop=0 speed=1.09x    
    (...)    
    frame=  890 fps= 31 q=29.0 q=5.0 size=    5339kB time=00:00:29.40 bitrate=1487.6kbits/s dup=653 drop=0 speed=1.01x    
    frame=  902 fps= 31 q=29.0 q=5.0 size=    5416kB time=00:00:29.80 bitrate=1488.9kbits/s dup=662 drop=0 speed=1.01x    
    [tls @ 0000000000e9a040] Writing encrypted data to socket failed
    av_interleaved_write_frame(): I/O error

    Error writing trailer of https://urlexemplo.com.br:/rota: I/O error
    frame=  919 fps= 29 q=-1.0 Lq=5.0 size=    5861kB time=00:00:30.53 bitrate=1572.4kbits/s dup=675 drop=0 speed=0.972x    
    video:6157kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown

    [tls @ 0000000000e9a040] Writing encrypted data to socket failed

    [tls @ 0000000000e9a040] Failed to send close message

    [libx264 @ 0000000000e888e0] frame I:230   Avg QP:17.57  size: 25800
    [libx264 @ 0000000000e888e0] frame P:243   Avg QP:25.21  size:   167
    [libx264 @ 0000000000e888e0] 
    frame B:446   Avg QP:25.19  size:    35
    [libx264 @ 0000000000e888e0] consecutive B-frames: 27.1%  5.7% 56.8% 10.4%
    [libx264 @ 0000000000e888e0] mb I  I16..4: 15.5% 73.8% 10.7%
    [libx264 @ 0000000000e888e0] mb P  I16..4:  0.5%  0.5%  0.0%  P16..4:  3.6%  0.1%  0.4%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:94.9%
    [libx264 @ 0000000000e888e0] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  0.9%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:99.1%  L0: 1.1% L1:98.9% BI: 0.0%
    [libx264 @ 0000000000e888e0] 8x8 transform intra:73.5% inter:100.0%
    [libx264 @ 0000000000e888e0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 51.1% 99.7% 98.6% inter: 0.1% 1.2% 0.0%
    [libx264 @ 0000000000e888e0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 35% 27% 19% 19%
    [libx264 @ 0000000000e888e0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 33% 21% 25%  4%  4%  3%  5%  2%  3%
    [libx264 @ 0000000000e888e0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 50% 21% 15%  3%  4%  2%  3%  1%  1%
    [libx264 @ 0000000000e888e0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 75%  5%  9% 12%
    [libx264 @ 0000000000e888e0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.8% UV:0.4%
    [libx264 @ 0000000000e888e0] ref P L0: 72.5%  1.8% 18.5%  7.2%
    [libx264 @ 0000000000e888e0] ref B L0: 91.4%  8.6%

    [libx264 @ 0000000000e888e0]
 ref B L1: 100.0%  0.0%
    [libx264 @ 0000000000e888e0] kb/s:1564.33

    Conversion failed!
```

**It looks like the error is I/O and video conversion.**
Error 1: Writing encrypted data to socket failed av_interleaved_write_frame(): I/O error

Error 2: (libx264) Conversion failed!

The report is too big to put here, so I'll put the link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/azfrmvnurypjjte/ffmpeg-20171128-111552.log?dl=0

Comment: Try to specify the output format as `-f ffm`. See [Connecting your input sources](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/ffserver#Connectingyourinputsources).

Comment: Not an ffmpeg issue. Has to do with your destination. HTTP(S) to another URL works for me.

Comment: @Mulvya : The first error was solved, but it generated new ones. Could you help me? I made a second edition and added all the details.

Comment: @harrymc : The first error was solved, but it generated new ones. Could you help me? I made a second edition and added all the details.